# jquery/ajax code don't work on firefox but on other browser works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My problem is this, i have created an input text and a button just like in this image: 
[image]

The system is very simple, you enter a number and you hit go to set in database this possition using ajax. 
i tried this code with Chrome, Internet Explorer 9 and Edge and Firefox (51.0.1 (32-bit)) but it seems that on firefox the code does not work.
What culd be the problem?
Here is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function () {

                            $("#set_image_pos_btn<?php echo $image->id; ?>").click(function () {
                                event.preventDefault();

                                var image_id = <?php echo $image->id; ?>;
                                var image_position = $("#image_position_value<?php echo $image->id; ?>").val();

                                $.ajax({
                                    url: '<?php echo base_url("image/pozitie"); ?>',
                                    data: {id: image_id, position: image_position},
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        $("#image_position_value<?php echo $image->id; ?>").html(data);
                                    }
                                });

                            });

                        });
                    </script>
```

And here is the php code:

```
function pozitie() {
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $position = $this->input->post('position');

    if(isset($id)) {

        $update = $this->image_model->_update($id, array('position' => $position));

        if($update) {
            $image = $this->image_model->get_where_row('id', $id);
            echo $image->position;
        } else {
            echo "eroare";
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Check Firefox's console for errors. Could be a security issue.

Comment: Firefox does not provide `event` as a global variable. It's passed as an argument to the event handler function. When using jQuery, you should not use the global `event` anyway (unless you *really* have a good reason).

Comment: ReferenceError: event is not defined
 <anonim> 
 m.event.dispatch
 m.event.add/r.handle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the e parameter to the click event, then it will work.

```
click(function (e) {
```

Also: you should care about error handling.

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
.done(function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
.fail(function() {
  alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
  alert( "complete" );
});
```

Comment: try console.log in firefox to see if the click event is triggered.

Also depending on the jQuery version you are using you can try to use .on('click', function(e) { ... });

I think it works since jQuery 2, but I am not sure. Try it, if the click event is not triggered in Firefox.